# Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: android, android-navigation-view

На версиях более новых всё работает отлично!А на младших версиях,вот такая ошибка.
Выручайте.
Ошибка на Android 4.4.2:

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{by.ittech.test_chat/by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2412)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                            at by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71)
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458)
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178)
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292) 
                                                                            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
                                                                            at by.ittech.test_chat.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:71) 
                                                                            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5458) 
                                                                            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307) 
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                         Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f02017a a=-1 r=0x7f02017a}
                                                                            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:3415)
                                                                            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
                                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:133)
                                                                            at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:123)
                                                                            at com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.ShaderImageView.<init>(ShaderImageView.java:24)
                                                                            at com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView.<init>(CircularImageView.java:18)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.inflateHeaderView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:211) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.inflateHeaderView(NavigationView.java:269) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:178) 
                                                                            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:100)
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

nav_header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@color/dark_main"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="36dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <com.github.siyamed.shapeimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.28"
        android:src="@drawable/man"
        app:siBorderColor="@color/white"
        app:siBorderWidth="2dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_nick"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Имя"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/main_email"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_marginBottom="11dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/main_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:text="e-mail"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/main_photo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/main_photo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: а у вас в ресурсах есть **drawable/man**?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да. В расширении png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась,убрав картинку        android:src="@drawable/man"